# What are the "more reliable methods of communication" Dumbledore describes in Order of the Phoenix?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Dumbledore says to Harry,

> I should explain that members of the Order of the Phoenix have more reliable methods of communicating than the fire in Dolores Umbridge's office.

What exactly are these methods of communication and why couldn't Harry and co. use it as well since all other methods were monitored?

Comment: You know, obviously wizards aren't keen on using muggle technology, but wouldn't it sometimes be more convenient just to have mobile phones available in case of emergency?

Answer (score 7):

They used a [Patronus messenger spell](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/messenger-spell/). It was shown a few times through the series, especially in the latter books. Since patronuses are unique for the individuals this makes it usefull to know who exactly the sender is. Since the patronus charm is quite difficult with a mental component it is most likely that is is almost impossible to cast under duress.

Why Harry and co. weren't taught how to do that is unknown.

Comment: Not unique. Harry and James, Snape and Lily, and Fred and George all have the same ones. Tonks starts the same as Luna, then changes to be the same as Lupin. McGonagall and Umbridge you'd have to look closely to tell the difference.

Comment: It's weird that Dumbledore wouldn't just say "yeah we use patronuses to talk to each other". Why make it so mysterious?

Comment: @sudhanva - because HP is a poorly written series for children and everything is vague and mysterious?

Comment: @Davor - Also, perhaps because it isn't a good idea to give information it would be dangerous for the enemy to know to people who don't [need to know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_to_know) that information. That's basic [InfoSec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security)

Comment: @T.E.D. - come now. The whole series is absolutely strewn with characters withholding information for no other reason than to make things sound mysterious to the reader. No need to be coy, or pretend that JKR was thinking about InfoSec.

Comment: @Davor - Well yes, that's the old in-universe vs. out-out-universe explanation debate that we seem to have here rather a lot. Do I think the unemployed school teacher who can't even wrap her mind around the concept of gender identity, fully understands the nuances of InfoSec and wrote everything accordingly? No. However, if one wants an explanation in-universe that makes sense here, this one does.

Comment: @T.E.D. Gender identity? Why aim so high? She can't even grasp the bloody days of the week.

Answer (score 6):

Not to mention even Harry had a more reliable /secure way of communicating at hand, but did not (bother to) know at that time: The two-way mirror Sirius gave him.

In the books this is somewhat of a final "Think before you act" towards Harry, as he could have easily contacted Sirius for the entirety of the story / book.

It is never mentioned, but this mirror is not depicted as something unique / rare, so the Order members might have each had such "video-walkie-talkies".